# after launching the server I have the following problem in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, enhanced-ecommerce

I work on an e-commerce and I have just set up the routing system but the following error occurs on the terminal after launching the server I have already created and coded the page 11pages all configured for firebase and for vue-router and when I correct the errors until I appear I only see a simple blank page and nothing else the content of my pages no longer display but without the implementation of vue-router its working but no routing between the pages

This dependency was not found:

> - core-js/modules/es.array.splice.js in ./node_modules/cache->loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel->loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue->loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/Views/Cart.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run:
`npm install --save core-js/modules/es.array.splice.js`

please I knew you the problem I tried to install the dependency that I was asked I could not

Answer (score 0):

Install the dependency like this

`npm i core-js`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js